# Rank of homology basis in Ahlfors' Complex Analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

In Ahlfors' Complex Analysis book Section 4.4.7, he decomposes the complement in the extended plane of a region $\Omega$ into connected components. He then constructs a collection of cycles $\gamma_i$ in $\Omega$, one for each component, such that every cycle $\gamma$ in $\Omega$ is homologous to an *integer* linear combination of the $\gamma_i$.

Each homology class for $\Omega$ is represented uniquely as such an integer linear combination. He then mentions that there are other such collections of cycles that also serve as a homology basis, but that

> ...by an elementary theorem in linear algebra we may conclude that every homology basis has the same number of elements.

I think I understand at least partially why this should be true: Homology classes of cycles in $\Omega$ form a module over the integers, and because we've already found the basis $\gamma_i$ we know that it's in fact a free module on these generators. We know from *slightly more than elementary algebra* that the rank of a finitely generated free module over a commutative ring is well-defined.

**Question:** What is the *elementary linear algebra* argument that he's using?

**EDIT:** Does the fact that it's a module over the integers help out? Can you embed the module of homology classes into its module of fractions (without using a basis to do so), show that the homology basis for the module becomes a basis for the module of fractions as a vector space over the rationals. Then you could use the linear algebra result for dimension of a vector space?

Thank you!

Comment: I've no idea on homology classes, but my intuition tells me it's the theorem that states that every basis for a vector space has the same amount of elements. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I really do think he's just taking it for granted that the relevant "elementary" arguments about the notions of dimension and basis from linear algebra over a field carry over, *mutatis mutandis*, to the notions of rank and basis in the theory of finitely-generated free modules over a commutative ring. Whether or not this is a justifiable leap or a sneaky bit of sweeping things under the rug, however, is a matter of taste.

Comment: The homology group is a torsion-free, finitely-generated abelian group, aka a free abelian group of finite rank. The uniqueness of rank of a free abelian group (or a free module over a PID) is probably considered "elementary" by Ahlfors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concerning your edit, yes, you can embed the integer homology group into the homology with rational coefficients. You can define chains with rational coefficients for the paths, a cycle is a chain with empty boundary (the boundary of a path is $\text{endpoint} - \text{startpoint}$, the boundary of a chain is the corresponding linear combination of the boundaries of the constituent paths). The integral of $f$ over $\Gamma = \sum c_i\gamma_i$ is

$$\sum c_i\cdot \int_{\gamma_i} f(z)\,dz,$$

the winding number of a chain around a point $a$ not on the trace of the chain is

$$n(\Gamma,a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum c_i\int_{\gamma_i} \frac{dz}{z-a},$$

two cycles are homologous if $n(\Gamma_1,a) = n(\Gamma_2,a)$ for all $a\notin \Omega$.

A more or less tedious verification shows that $[\Gamma]_\mathbb{Z} \mapsto [\Gamma]_\mathbb{Q}$ is a well-defined embedding of the integer homology into the rational homology.

But determining the rank of a finitely generated free abelian group $B$ by counting the elements of the $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space $B/pB$ for a prime $p$ ($p = 2$ for example) seems easier and more elementary to me.

Comment: What if a domain $\Omega$ has infinitely many connected components in its complement? How do we define a homology basis now? Is there a generalization?

Comment: You can generalise the concept. For the definition of the homology group, it doesn't matter whether the complement has finitely many or infinitely many components. I think the homology with integer coefficients would still be a free abelian group, but I'm not sure. The homology with rational coefficients would naturally be a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. In simple cases like $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$, any cycle can only enclose finitely many components of the complement, and you have a homology basis made up from cycles that enclose one component. In general, though, a cycle can enclose

Comment: infinitely many components, and you don't get such a simple homology basis. I doubt whether it's in general even possible to describe one.